# How do you complete the challenge "Can't have enough Ram"?

Tags: dead-island

I have no idea how to ram enemies.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only get this challenge by using [Sam B](http://deadisland.wikia.com/wiki/Sam_B)'s Tackle skill.

From the [wiki](http://deadisland.wikia.com/wiki/Can%27t_have_enough_ram):

- 25 enemies need to be rammed at level one.
- 50 enemies need to be rammed at level two.
- 250 enemies need to be rammed at level three.
- 500 enemies need to be rammed at level four.

Here is a youtube video for demonstration:

Comment: Note that tackling is essentially sprinting into an enemy (once you've got at least Level 1 tackling in the Combat skill tree). This works in both normal mode and Fury.

Comment: yes, just be aware its a huge stamina hit to perform a tackle

Comment: True ... even with Level 3 tackling, it still uses stamina. Prior to that, it might be better to save it for Fury, when stamina isn't an issue, particularly if you've upgraded it so that it lasts longer.